# How to store data objects that change all the time?

Tags: nosql, datastore

I have a complex data problem and no idea how to solve : i want to create an app where my users can create processes and add data to these processes.

Example :

1. UserA creates a form1 with 2 fields (input/textarea) and saves his form as a process
2. He starts process1 and fills up his form with data - data is stored.
3. UserA creates a form2 with 34 fields...
4. UserA starts a new process2 with form 1 and store different data

Storing the forms is kind of easy - but i can't figure out how to store the data from these forms since they are to vary all the time

I've thought to use Nosql db but i'm lost passed that point.

Any idea welcome !